# Remove all Carriage Returns and Spaces from String begin and end

Tags: c#

Using C# 9 I am removing new lines from the begin and end of a String:

```
myString = myString.Trim('\r', '\n');
```

However, I need to remove all new lines and spaces from string begin and end:

```
myString = "  \n   \n The text content  \n of my string\n  \n\n \n"
```

The result for this string would be:

```
myString = "The text content  \n of my string"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Trim without parameters _Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the current string._ Meaning that anything that is a _white-space_ is removed. Newlines are whitespace. See [char.IsWhiteSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace?view=net-5.0)

Comment: You could specify additional characters to trim, including space and tab besides \n and \r.

Comment: As a senior developer with such an established score here on SO I'm quite surprised that you're asking such a basic question. An implementation of `Trim` exists in most  languages or frameworks today.

Comment: @silkfire I was missing something in Trim method maybe because I have been doing a lot of Frontend and getting back to C# now ... And I found out that the unexpected results I was getting had origin on other parts of my code and not on Trim method. Being developing for years in many projects does not make a person perfect ... At least not me ... ;-) Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Steve suggested, you need to use the [`String.Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-5.0) method on the `myString` variable to get rid of such characters

```cs
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string myString = "  \n   \n The text content  \n of my string\n  \n\n \n";
        Console.WriteLine("Before Trim: \"{0}\"", myString);
        
        myString = myString.Trim();
        Console.WriteLine("After Trim: \"{0}\"", myString);
    }
}
```

The output of the above example would be

```
Before Trim: "  
   
 The text content  
 of my string
  

 
"
After Trim: "The text content  
 of my string"
```

Check out this example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KbTaHF